# Training in Python and Deploying in Spark

Tags: python-3.x, scala, apache-spark-mllib, xgboost, apache-spark-ml

Is it possible to train an XGboost model in python and use the saved model to predict in spark environment ?  That is, I want to be able to train the XGboost model using sklearn, save the model. Load the saved model in spark and predict in spark. Is this possible ?

edit:
Thanks all for the answer , but my question is really this. I see the below issues when I train and predict different bindings of XGBoost.

1. During training I would be using XGBoost in python, and when  predicting I would be using XGBoost in mllib.
2. I have to load the saved model from XGBoost python (Eg: XGBoost.model file) to be predicted in spark, would this model be compatible to be used with the predict function in the mllib
3. The data input formats of both XGBoost in python and XGBoost in spark mllib are different. Spark takes vector assembled format but with python, we can feed the dataframe as such. So, how do I feed the data when I am trying to predict in spark with a model trained in python. Can I feed the data without vector assembler ? Would XGboost predict function in spark mllib take non-vector assembled data as input ?

Comment: So, you want to train the XGBoost model using spark mllib or sklearn.

Comment: Edited the question. Do check.

Comment: you can use ```spark``` as an orchestration system to both train and predict ```sklearn``` models via ```spark-sklearn``` module.  it will push iterations of each model to different ```spark``` executors.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your python script on spark using `spark-submit` command so that can compile your python code on spark and then you can predict the value in spark.

Comment: But when I use python scrip on spark-submit, I will have to use spark mllib, right ? I want to train using sklean and predict using mllib.

Comment: Are you suggesting that we can run python code in spark environment using spark-submit ?

Answer (score 0):

you can

1. load data/ munge data using pyspark sql,
2. then bring data to local driver using collect/topandas(performance bottleneck)
3. then train xgboost on local driver
4. then prepare test data as RDD,
5. broadcast the xgboost model to each RDD partition, then predict data in parallel

This all can be in one script, you spark-submit, but to make the things more concise, i will recommend split train/test in two script.

Because step2,3 are happening at driver level, not using any cluster resource, your worker are not doing anything

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try it. But I again, want someone to really confirm that this is possible. the XGBoost in spark takes vector assembled data format. and in python, we will feed in the dataframe as such. How would spark deal with this variation in input formats ?

Comment: I see, your xgboost binding is in scala but you want to train locally in python? two questions, if your scala mllib already have xgboost binding, why not train distributed use scala pyspark.mllib? why do you want to predict using the distributed version, you can still achieve distributed training using trained-model?

Comment: My training accuracy of XGboost in mllib is really low, and I am not able to figure out why. the test auc is python is 90% where as it is some 80% in spark. :)

Comment: distributed training is just not mature yet. i saw it a lot as well. In this case, train on driver, prepare pyspark RDD, each partition is subset of your data, broadcast your xgboost to each partition, use map partition to combine data to a dmatrix, then predict use the model

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar implementation of what you are looking for.  I have a SO post explaining details as I am trying to troubleshoot the errors described in the post to get the code in the notebook working .

[XGBoost Spark One Model Per Worker Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58595442/xgboost-spark-one-model-per-worker-integration)

The idea is to train using `xgboost` and then via `spark` orchestrate each model to run on a `spark worker` and then predictions can be applied via `xgboost` `predict_proba()` or `spark ml` `predict()`.